# Ajax mysql duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, ajax, post

before i post this i already looked up for my problem. so here it is

I'm using ajax to get a value using post. but it appears that when i insert it to my database it produces duplicate entry. here's my ajax code

```
var receiverUserIds = FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'Test App',
    },

    function (receiverUserIds) {
        $.each(receiverUserIds.to, function (i, v) {
            // console.log(receiverUserIds.request + " " + v);
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo $config["base_url"]; ?>/main/saverequestinfo/?signed_request=<?php echo $_REQUEST["signed_request"]; ?>',
                data: {
                    request_id: receiverUserIds.request,
                    receiver_id: v
                },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (d) {
                    console.log(receiverUserIds.request + " " + v);
                }
            });
        });
    }
    //http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
);
```

this is the code called by ajax

```
function saverequestinfo() {
     $data = array(
    'inv_user_id' => 1,
    'inv_request_id' => $_POST['request_id'],
    'inv_user_fbid' => $this->fb->getUser(),
    'inv_receiver_fbid' => $_POST['receiver_id'],
    'inv_liked' => fb_isLiked($this->fb)
);

$this->main->insertrequest('invitedfriends', $data);
```

}

and this is my model:

```
function insertrequest($tbl_name, $data) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $qry = "INSERT INTO `".$tbl_name."` (";
    $c = count($data);
    $cc = 0;
    $f = "";
    $fv = "";
    foreach($data as $i=>$v) {
        $f .= $i;
        $fv .= "'".$v."'";
        if($cc<$c-1) {
            $f .= ",";
            $fv .= ",";
        }
        $cc++;
    }
    $qry .= $f.") VALUES(".$fv.")";

    if ($this->conn->query($qry) !== TRUE) {
        echo $this->conn->error;
        die();
    }
    $this->conn->query($qry);
}
```

Comment: Please post your code for the page called by Ajax, and your database structure.  It appears that some field in your database is configured to not allow duplicate values. You're probably inserting something that has already been stored in the database.

Comment: hi thank you for the response. i kinda fixed my problem but in a very odd way. i created a new function in my model then delete every duplicate entry. if you can help me solve this the right way. ill be more than glad to apply it to my code.